# Custom Angular Filter to select ng-repeat items on object key name - Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `$http` service that retrieves user payment data. This data comes in the form of a JSON object - I asked for an array but the backend guys gave me an object! The object data structure looks something like this...

```
{
    creditCardData: Array[3], // this is an array of objects, each object is Credit Card data, in this case the array has 3 objects but can have many
    directDebitData: Array[0] // this is an array of objects, each object is Direct Debit data, the arrray is empty here, but the array can have unlimited objects
    errorMessage: null // this is either null or a string
    invoiceData: Array[1] // this is an array of objects, each object is Invoice data, in this case the array has 1 objects...
    paymentAvailable: true // a boolean
    selectedCreditCardData: Object // this is either an object or null
    selectedDirectDebitData: null // this is either an object or null
    selectedInvoiceData: null // this is either an object or null
}
```

Now I have an `ng-repeat` in my view and I wish to only repeat on certain items, so I wish to be able to check by key value (name) and only show the data if there is a match, so for example only show data for the keys with names 'creditCardData', 'directDebitData', 'invoiceData'.

My plan was to have a custom filter that would determine the key name/value and then add this to a new object if applicable before returning the object, something like this:

```
<!-- paymentData = $scope.paymentData - an object like the one above -->
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, prop) in paymentData track by $index | ObjectKeyFilter:prop:key">
```

And My filter (not tested) would be like so...

```
  .filter('ObjectKeyFilter', function () {

    return function (item, prop, key) {
      // items is the ng-repeat index, prop the data and key the name
      var tempObj = {}
      // do comparison on key create a new object... ImportantL this logic may not be correct at this stage, for explaination only
      if(key === 'directDebitData' || key === 'creditCardData' || key === 'invoiceData') {
        tempObj[key] = prop;
      }
      return tempObj;
    };
  });
```

Now so far I get the following error and I don't know why as I am using the `track by` syntax -  `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: (key, prop) in paymentData track by $index | ObjectKeyFilter:prop:key, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: []`

I am unsure if my approach is correct and whether a custom filter is approproate. A colleague has told me (and I have checked this in the documentation) that filters should only be used when iterating through Arrays and not with objects! My question is... is using a custom filter correct with my current situation / requirements?

Thanks in advance. If my wording is bad just add a comment and I will edit to be more clear.

Comment: less code to just map a new object in controller or service. Filters are for arrays ..yes

Comment: `Duplicate key: undefined` something fishy with your`$scope.paymentData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.filter('ObjectKeyFilter', function () {

    return function (item) {
      var tempObj = {}
      angular.forEach(item, function(value, key) {
        if(key === 'directDebitData' || key === 'creditCardData' || key === 'invoiceData') {
          tempObj[key] = value;
        }
      });
      return tempObj;
    };
  });
```

In html:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, prop) in (data | ObjectKeyFilter) track by $index">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jITyqNmkJMiSc7NmeA19?p=preview

P.S. If you are not satisfied with data retrieved from rest call, you can just change it manually - reorder whatever, etc. I.e. in ng-resource there is transformRequest function for this.

Comment: This answer is correct but I think you're idea about changing it manually (I'll do this is the data service) is easier than writing a filter...